# How do I set the column and row indexes on a multidimensional list in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I have a set of data I'm retrieving from a google sheet. It comes back in the format:

```
[['Incident Severity', '# of Incidents by Severity'], ['Sev 1', '0'], ['Sev 2', '0'], ['Sev 3', '3'], ['Sev 4', '2']]
```

I've imported it into Pandas using from_records, which gives me the following using df.head():

```
                   0                           1
0  Incident Severity  # of Incidents by Severity
1              Sev 1                           0
2              Sev 2                           0
3              Sev 3                           3
4              Sev 4                           2
```

however the first row needs to be set as the header and the first column should be an index. I have managed to change the column headers by doing the following:

```
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df.reindex(df.index.drop(0))
```

Which gives me:

```
0 Incident Severity # of Incidents by Severity
1             Sev 1                          0
2             Sev 2                          0
3             Sev 3                          3
4             Sev 4                          2
```

How can I drop the first index column so that I end up with the following table:

```
Incident Severity # of Incidents by Severity
            Sev 1                          0
            Sev 2                          0
            Sev 3                          3
            Sev 4                          2
```

I'm quite new to pandas and dataframes so forgive me if I'm missing something obvious. I have tried to google it, but not finding what I need to know!

Comment: Have a look at `set_index`

Comment: Thank you I will take a look at that :)

Answer (score 1):

Use indexing of list for create `DataFrame`:

```
L = [['Incident Severity', '# of Incidents by Severity'],
      ['Sev 1', '0'],
      ['Sev 2', '0'], 
      ['Sev 3', '3'], 
      ['Sev 4', '2']]

df = pd.DataFrame(L[1:], columns=L[0])
print (df)

  Incident Severity # of Incidents by Severity
0             Sev 1                          0
1             Sev 2                          0
2             Sev 3                          3
3             Sev 4                          2
```

Index is not possible remove, one solution (really bad) is convert index to empty values:

```
df.index = [''] * len(df)
print (df)
 Incident Severity # of Incidents by Severity
             Sev 1                          0
             Sev 2                          0
             Sev 3                          3
             Sev 4                          2
```

But if need write DataFrame with no index to file add parameter `index=False` to [`to_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html):

```
print (df.to_csv(index=False))
Incident Severity,# of Incidents by Severity
Sev 1,0
Sev 2,0
Sev 3,3
Sev 4,2
```

Comment: Wow. So simple! Awesome! I didn't know you could do that when you were importing the data! Thank you for the detailed and awesomely quick answer!